# How to detect side mouse clicks in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, mouseclick-event

Is it possible to detect using JavaScript when the user clicks the back/forward buttons that are the side of your mouse ? These are known as XButtons as far as I know, in .net at least. This is for a locally installed app so I don't need cross browser support, just something that works in IE.

Comment: @Greg Maybe I'm missing something, but how would onkeydown help in catching a (type of) mouse click ?

Comment: Ignore that last one, sorry, its late on the east cost +1 for the question though, its a good one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done.  The most sophisticated mouse click events you will get is left and right.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function testMouseClick()
    {
        if(event.button == 1)
        {
        alert("Left Mouse Click is Pressed..");
        }
        if(event.button == 2)
        {
        alert("Right Mouse Click is Pressed..");
        }               
    }
</script><
```

Answer (score 1):

No, don't think so, by the time it gets to the browser it's been translated into whatever action the button is bound to